# Taking the Decimal Part as an Integer Number without being calculated as decimal in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, excel-2007

I am sorry if the ans is available already but i tried finding and could't after spending much time. I am stuck in a very small issue.

The Problem is just like a math problem
I purchase different items with different packing qty

if i purchase pack of biscuit with 20 box in a carton
i received 10 carton and 15 box

I want to put the number in an excel cell as 10.15 and i want it to calculate it as 10+(15/20)*Rate

i tried

```
    A       B              C           D
  1 Rate    Packing qty    Received    Bill Amount
  2 100     20             10.15       =G6*(INT(H6)+((MOD(H6,1)/C1)))
```

but could not get the required results. Any one guide me how to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can utilize

```
=(INT(C2)+ MOD(C2,1)*100/B2)*100
```

[image]

Comment: Sir, it won't work when i ll receive 10 carton and 4 box, and i'll put 10.4, it will not give the correct ans :(

Comment: @AtifSheikh  If you are entering non-powers of 10 in the decimal portion of a number, then you **must** use leading 0's to differentiate `4` from `40`.  Else, if you entered `10.1` with a carton of 20, there would be no way of knowing if you meant `10+1` or `10+10`

Comment: You are right, i should start counting from .01 to .19 in case box packing are 20, let me try once

Comment: Its working, Thanks Sir Ron. I tried accepting answer, but its not accepted as i tried after 1 or more minutes.

Comment: @AtifSheikh Just use the `INT MOD` formula for now.  There may be a problem with the other.

Comment: @AtifSheikh That my be a connection or website issue. You should be able to accept the answer regardless of your status here.

Comment: That was also working fine, but i used int mod as its more familiar. Thanks....